# Navigation.navigate() is not redirecting and throwing error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native application and I use `navigation.navigate` throughout the application but in one case where I use it, it is not working and I am not sure why. I have an idea but I dont know how to fix it.

I have a component called `ConnectAgentComponent`. I have a touchableopacity view and when a user clicks on it, I want to redirect to a different screen. I am grabbing navigation from the props of the component. I then want it call `navigation.navigate('ContactScreen', {zpid, zpid})`

I think what is happening is that it is expecting me to pass in navigation from the parent component. When i call it from other components after grabbing it from the props part of the component, it works...

Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

Code:

```
const ContactAgentComponent = ({property, navigation}) => {

  const propertyAddress = property.address.streetAddress + ', ' + property.address.city +
    ', ' + property.address.state + ' ' + property.address.zipcode

  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Emails')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(navigation)
  }, [navigation])

  const contactScreen = (zpid) => {
    navigation.navigate('ContactAgentStack', {zpid: zpid})
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.connect}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Connect With An Agent</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.messageContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.message}>Interested in the property above, connect with one of our agents that will be able to assist you!</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
          <Image style={{height: 80, width: 80}} source={{uri: 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/portrait-white-man-isolated_53876-40306.jpg?w=2000'}}/>
          <View style={styles.contactContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Omar Jandali</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>DRE# 02151051</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Realty One Group</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>DRE# 0896421</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {contactScreen(property.zpid)}}>
        <View style={styles.buttoncontainer}>
          <Text style={styles.button}>Connect With Agent</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your navigator component as well

Comment: Follow this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/